# Postscript number of copies

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe, postscript

Is there a way to edit a postscript file, to add or increase the number of copies to be printed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add `/#copies 3 def` in the setup section - or the whole prolog section if it is missing.

```
   %!

   %%BeginProlog
   %%BeginSetup
   /#copies 3 def
   %%EndSetup
   %%EndProlog

   72 72 scale
   2 2 translate

   /Helvetica-Bold findfont .2 scalefont setfont
   0 3 moveto (Not too shabby) show

   /Times-Italic findfont 1 scalefont setfont
   0 0 1 setrgbcolor
   0 4 moveto (Niels Castle!) show

   showpage
```

To sum up the [PostScript Language Document Structuring Conventions Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/postscript/pdfs/5001.DSC_Spec.pdf) "If multiple copies of a document are desired, use the `#copies` key or the `setpagedevice` operator" and it goes on to discourage the use of the `copypage` operator.

You have to send the file to an imaging device to see it in effect - opening the PostScript file with GhostScript or Preview on Mac will just render one copy ignoring the operator.

Answer (score -1):

```
featurebegin{
  %%BeginNonPPDFeature: NumCopies 3
  3  /languagelevel where {pop languagelevel}{1} ifelse
  2 ge { 1 dict dup /NumCopies 4 -1 roll put setpagedevice }{ userdict /#copies 3 
  -1 roll put } ifelse
  %%EndNonPPDFeature
}featurecleanup
```